# Gridview selected row not working

Tags: gridview, row, selected

I have the following code:

```
GridViewProducts.SelectedIndex = 0;
GridViewRow row = GridViewProducts.SelectedRow;
```

But it's saying "ArgumentOutOfRangeException and the row is null

I want to be able to get data from the gridview by selecting the first row automatically.

Comment: on which grid event you are trying to fetch `GridViewProducts.SelectedRow;`, please share the complete method code

Answer (score 0):

The order of the code matters. Set the SelectedIndex before DataBind and get the Row after. If you try selecting a SelectedRow before DataBind it will fail since there are not selected rows yet.

```
GridView1.DataSource = source;
GridView1.SelectedIndex = 0;
GridView1.DataBind();
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
```